# Correct format for a naughty regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I am having trouble trying to put a regular expression in the right order. It's for C#, could anyone please help?

Im trying to replace the `sas` to say `yyy`.

Original: `sas sas2 sas-def def-sas SASsas`

The result should be

Result: `yyy yyy2 yyy-def def-yyy SASsas`

So you can see I want to replace the sas whenever it doesn't have a letter on either side of it.

Driving me nuts!

Comment: What have you come up with so far?

Comment: just imagine how many ways you can test in an hour :)  the closest i have so far is `\b([^a-z])sas\b`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use both a negative lookahead and a negative lookbehind:

```
(?<![a-zA-Z])sas(?![a-zA-Z])
```

Comment: will it permit digits as required by the author of this question?

Comment: Yep, true, some regex engines do consider digits as parts of words... Fixed to use lookaheads

Comment: it doesnt match `sas2`.  I just tested `\b([^a-z])sas\b` which seems to do the trick on an online test site, just writing it in to the code now to test

Comment: nope, that didnt work, gave me `sas sas2yyy-def defyyy SASsas` and on the other side ie `\bsas([^a-z])\b` gives me `yyyyyy yyydef def-yyySASsas`

Comment: I amended your code to look for a digit like so `(?<!\w)(\d)*sas(\d)*(?!\w)` and that seems to have done the trick :)

Comment: Sorry, just saw your comment now. FANTASTIC fge, much appreciated. Happy New Year!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding lookahead from both sides. You're actually interested in the context of the match and not only in the match itself.